# How to redirect rsyslog messages to some other path instead of /var/log

Tags: syslog

I am using the [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html) facility for logging. Everything is working fine; I am able to log the messages in `/var/log/MYlog.log` path.

But now my requirement is to log the message in some other path like `/opt/log/Somepath.log` instead of `/var/log`.

I tried modifying Path in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, but it only works if I give a log path under `/var/log/`.  Nothing else seems to work. I want the log Path to be a configurable path like `/opt/log/somePath.log`.

I have an entry like this in the file and it works fine:

```
local6.* /var/log/Mylog.log
```

Now if I change it like this:

```
local6.* /opt/log/Mylog.log
```

it does not generate the Mylog.log file in `/opt/log`.  The directory `/opt/log` is present.

After Modifying the configuration file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` I am Restarting the deamon again.

```
`/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`
```

And There is no possibility of any permission and security issue since both `/var/log` and `/opt/log` are having same permissions(I changed `/opt/log` permissions similar to the `/var/log`).

I am using CentOs 6.3. It is my local VM and there is no Chance of NFS.

Is there any way or trick so that I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual for the [`syslog` configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf)?  If not, why not?

Comment: that is what i am telling. I tried /opt/log/Mylog.log .But it is not working. It is not generating any file in /opt/log.

Comment: i don't have any file named syslog.conf. I have rsyslog.conf that is backward compatible to syslog.conf and it is looking into rsyslog.conf because when i give /var/log/Mylog.log it generates the file.

Comment: ok. @JonathanLeffler ihave updated the question. and this is how the configuration is.  local6.*                                                /var/log/Mylog.log   it works fine. Now if i change it like this local6.*                                                /opt/log/Mylog.log it does not generate the Mylog.log File in /opt/log and /opt/log is present and there is no permission issue.

Comment: You say you don't have a permission issue.  How do you know that?  What are the permissions on `/opt/log` (owner:group:mode)?  Is there any chance it is a network-mounted file system (NFS or some such)?  Is there any information in the log files for your syslog daemon about the altered configuration?  Have you restarted the daemon or otherwise told it that its configuration has changed, or does it spot that automatically?

Comment: **/opt/log** has permissions 777 for owner group and others. This is my local centos virtual machine No chance of NFS. I restart the rsyslog services using **/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart** command after altering the configuration. I could not find the log file of syslog deamon but i am pretty sure that restarting the service is having effect. since if I put **/var/log/Mylog.log** in conf file and restart the service it works.

Comment: OK; please edit that information into the question.  Just because I make a comment, it does not mean you should respond with a comment.  When you provide substantive information, add it to the question.  Important information from your last message: Centos; VM; no NFS; you have restarted rsyslog; you can see changes when you change the name under `/var/log`.  One possibility is that the syslog daemon won't write in a publicly writable directory — security-conscious programs won't do that. Using 777 permission is essentially always a dubious proposition (`/tmp` uses `1777` which is different!).

Comment: I had the similar kind of problem, check if my blog helps you - http://www.tune2wizard.com/linux-process-table-process-management-syslog-daemon/ Please check the syslog part.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler and SHREYAS for your comments, but Nothing seems to be fixing this issue. :(

Answer (score 5):

The problem is selinux. SELinux will prevent processes that are labeled `syslogd_t` to write to files that are (probably) labeled default_t. So we need to label the file with something syslogd_t can write to. Files in `/var/log` are labeled `var_log_t`, a type `syslogd_t` can surely write to.
Temporarily You can achieve this by changing the label of /opt/log directory.

```
chcon -R -t var_log_t /opt/log
```

You can check the modified labeling using

```
  ls -Z /opt/log
```

that will give output something like this

```
drwxrwxrwx. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0 log
```

So after this you will be able redirect syslog to any other directories. For permanent solution you need to write SELinux policy.